# Deleting row with a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a MySQL table called 'node', with a foreign key named 'parentNodeId' which references another row in this table; this way, I can have nodes within other nodes through a foreign key.

Ok then, the problem is when I want to delete a row in this table, a SQL error outputs:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
>   (`PFeCommerce`.`node`, CONSTRAINT `FK_857FE84548C76A8E` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`parentNodeId`) REFERENCES `node` (`id`))

So I go to the row that I want to delete, and I set the field 'parentNodeId' with a NULL value. But the error still happening.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the error is that ANOTHER row (not the one you are trying to DELETE) has that row's id (i.e., the id of the row you are tring to delete) in its parentNodeId column.

Answer (score 1):

Thre problem is not with you wanting to delete a child node, but that the node that you want to delete is a parent node for another element

See 2 cases:

```
parent node // this one has id = 1
    \
   child node // this one has parentNodeID set to 1
```

if you delete the child node, there is no reason for error as only the child node depends on the parent node, no other data depends on child node

in your case:

```
parent node // id = 1
     \
   child node   // this is the one you want to delete, parentNodeId = 1
       \
      another child node
```

now what your are doing, is you delete "child node" but another node (another child node) has its id in the parentNodeId field so if you would delete the "child node", there would be a relation pointing to non-existing record, which causes an error due to key constraint